# Wordpress (view table product)

Tags: wordpress, product

does anyone know where wordpress saves products when added from admin screen?
I need to see the product table on the database wordpress ..
Does anyone know how to do?

Thank You

Comment: What do you mean product table? afaik wordpress doesn't have a product table by default...

Answer (score 0):

All posts and products in case of woocommerce are stored in `wp_posts` table.
And in `wp_posts` table you can filter the results for 'post_type' column to product.

Hope this helps.